# Discord BOT, select random values from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, bots, discord.js

I'm trying to build my own Discord bot and I want it to send some random things from an array i already have, but don't want them to be the same (should be different every time). For example, I have 5 things in my array and I want to reply with 3 different elements from the array.

This is my code at the moment:

```js
var question = ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4", "answer5"];
var temparray = [];
                    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
                        
                        for(j=0;j<domande.length;j++){
                            temparray[i] = domande[Math.floor(Math.random() * domande.length)];
                            temparray[j] = temparray[i];
                            if(!temparray[i] === temparray[j]){
                                
                            }
                        }
                        console.log(temparray[i]);
                    }
```

[I dont want this to happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thX3w.png)

Are 2 for way to much, or am I missing something there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can shuffle the array and then take the first couple of elements. Here is an example using the [Fisher-Yates Shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle).

```js
var question = ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4", "answer5"];
for(let i = question.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
  let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));//or Math.random() * (i + 1) | 0
  let temp = question[idx];
  question[idx] = question[i];
  question[i] = temp;
}
let randomValues = question.slice(0, 3);
console.log(randomValues);
```

Alternatively, a destructuring assignment can be used to facilitate swapping the elements.

```js
var question = ["answer1", "answer2", "answer3", "answer4", "answer5"];
for(let i = question.length - 1; i > 0; i--){
  let idx = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));//or Math.random() * (i + 1) | 0
  [question[i], question[idx]] = [question[idx], question[i]];
}
let randomValues = question.slice(0, 3);
console.log(randomValues);
```